# How to take infinite number of arguments in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am making a Python command line tool with argparse that decodes and encodes Morse code. Here is the code:

```
parser.add_argument('-d','--decode',dest="Morse",type=str,help="Decode Morse to Plain text .")
parser.add_argument('-e','--encode',dest="text",type=str,help="Encode plain text into Morse code .")
```

when I type more that one argument after encode or decode it returns this:

```
H4k3r\Desktop> MorseCli.py -e Hello there
usage: MorseCli.py [-h] [-d MORSE] [-e TEXT] [-t] [-v]
MorseCli.py: error: unrecognized arguments: there
```

How will I take more arguments and not just the first word?

Comment: By the way,It works perfectly when there is only one argument.

Comment: Use double-quotes when passing the argument(s): `MorseCli.py -e "Hello there"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaulM. It works now and gives the correct output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell splits the input into separate strings on space, so

```
MorseCli.py -e Hello there
```

`sys.argv` that the parser sees is

```
['MorseCli.py', '-e', 'Hello', 'there']
```

With `nargs='+'` you can tell the parser to accept multiple words, but the parsing result is a list of strings:

```
args.encode = ['Hello', 'there']
```

The quoting suggestion keeps the shell from splitting those words

```
['MorseCli.py', '-e', 'Hello there']
```